# Are CMake macros/definitions accessible from source files?

Tags: c++, cmake, macros

Are the default CMake macros/definitions exposed to the source files being build?

For instance, can I access `CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION` from a `main.cpp`?

I understand I can just force them into the source files by creating a new macro with `set()` and `add_compile_definitions()`, but was looking for a cleaner / less redundant way of achieving this.

Comment: No, CMake variables are not the same as preprocessor macros, so they are not accessible. I guess the easiest thing is to make a list of variables and use `add_compile_definitions()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. CMake variables such as CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION are not accessible to the source files.